# Seeding in mongodb database tables in laravel 5

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5.1, database

I am trying to seed tables in mongodb but it shows error like this:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\student-information-system\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 390

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Call to a member function prepare() on null
```

How to seed in mongodb database tables in laravel 5?

Comment: I get same error when I run seed command 
any solution ?

Comment: It may help you https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/blob/master/tests/seeds/UserTableSeeder.php